# Как правильно: сЕссия или сЭссия?

Tags: произношение

В интернете пишут, что оба варианта допустимы в речи. Хотелось бы узнать, какой из них официальнее с точки зрения орфографии? Спасибо!

Comment: "В речи" - в произношении, или все-таки в орфогафии?

Comment: В речи, в произношении

Comment: Тогда я рекомендую подкорректировать вопрос, например заменить "орфографию" на "опфоэпию".

Answer (score 3):

В орфографии только "сессия", никак иначе.

Answer (score 2):

В Орфоэпическом словаре русского языка «сессия» входит в число слов с неустойчивым произношением, то есть допускается и твёрдое, и мягкое произношение согласного «с». При этом мягкое произношение отмечается как наиболее предпочтительное.